# Residue theorem, double pole, sinh.

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

how can I use the residue theorem to calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, \frac{e^{-i x}}{(\sinh x)^2}$$

Im confused about how to tackle the double pole at $x=in\pi$. Thanks!

Comment: You realize that the integral of interest does not converge since it is $O(x^{-2})$ as $x \to 0$.  But I did provide an answer to your question regarding second order poles.

Comment: If the integral of this type were finite, e.g., if you instead asked for the value of $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-i x}}{\cosh^2{x}} $$ then it would be much easier to use a rectangular contour.  That way, you need only worry about the pole at $z=i \pi/2$ in that case.  Unfortunately, the integral you are showing is divergent and not worth bothering with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the residue of $f$ at $z_0$ for a pole of order $m$ we have

$$\text{Res}(z_0,f(z))=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left((z-z_0)^n f(z)\right)$$

So, for $f(z)=\frac{e^{-iz}}{(\sinh z)^2}$, $n=2$ and $z=im\pi$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}(im\pi,f(z))&=\frac{1}{(2-1)!} \lim_{z\to im\pi}\frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}\left((z-im\pi)^2 \frac{e^{-iz}}{(\sinh z)^2}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to im\pi}\frac{d}{dz}\left((z-im\pi)^2 \frac{e^{-iz}}{(\sinh z)^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

---

Footnote: The integral of interest diverges at $x=0$!

Comment: Did you happen to notice that the integral under question is not finite?

Comment: @RonGordon Then the OP will see a divergent series

Comment: @RonGordon How did you know so fast?

Comment: @RonGordon The zero in the denominator at $x=0$ is a hint.  Not even a Cauchy Principal Value saves the day here.